# Reliable blob state in Azure Service Fabric?

Tags: azure-service-fabric

Is there a recommended way work with blobs as reliable state in Azure Service Fabric?

I see two options:

1. Implement a chunking mechanism and store chunks in a reliable collection. This option has a pretty heavy development/maintenance burden though.
2. Store blobs externally (Azure Blob Storage). This option couples the service with Azure though. We would have to provide our own abstraction and implementation for running in an on-premises cluster.

Maybe there is a reliable state provider/manager for blobs already available somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those are your two best options currently. There isn't a blob state provider or service built in today. If you do store blobs in reliable collections, I would recommend chunking to reduce replication traffic. You may even consider building a blob storage service that uses a reliable dictionary to store chunks, deploy the service with multiple partitions for better distribution, and then provide a client for it that takes a blob, chunks, and distributes.

Comment: Thank you. Are there plans for adding a blob state provider (or service) to the service fabric framework in the future? It's something like what you describe that I had in mind. Just didn't want to go ahead with it if there was something similar already available.

Comment: No, no plans currently. I usually recommend Azure blob storage for this, which if you're on-prem, you can get with Azure Stack, but otherwise it shouldn't be terribly difficult to build your own with Reliable Services.

Comment: I'm revisiting this issue after more than two years. Firstly, has anything happened on this matter - are there any plans for making a system "Blob Service"? If not, what would you recommend for a good chunk size? I'm thinking either something like 4KB or 4MB.

Answer (score 0):

The web app example backups and restores a service state in a blob storage. You can do the same if you inherit from ActorService instead of Actor. So you are able to make backups to azure storage.

I implemented for my company a failover system which backups in a blob storage. The storage is relativly slow, so it is not recommended to use it as default state location.