# Bind Microsoft Stateless Service to Azure Storage Blob?

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-service-fabric, azure-webjobs

I'm developing a Stateless Service which will be in charge to process the blobs uploaded to a certain azure storage blob container. Is there a way to bind this Stateless Service to the blob the same way it can be done using Azure WebJobs?

As a workaround I was thinking of having a binded WebJob to that Azure Storage Blob Container and calling the Stateless Service everytime new blobs are uploaded.

Any sugestions or examples?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm not sure there is, based on the answers here [Reliable blob state in Azure Service Fabric?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36395536/reliable-blob-state-in-azure-service-fabric)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible to use the WebJob SDK in ASF services and use a blob trigger.

You can also use an Azure Function with a blob trigger, that then calls a service hosting a web api.

Comment: I think the second suggestion will fit our requiriements better, thanks!